# Read file contents the WP way

Tags: widgets

I'm developing a sidebar widget. I need to read a `txt` file in a particular directory of the website. I can do it with `file_get_contents` or `readfile` PHP functions, but what's the best way to safely do it in Wordpress?

(I don't know if the information is useful, but once red the content, I simply need to `echo` it)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what do you mean "safely" what can be not safe with reading files?

Comment: @MarkKaplun : maybe we should ask this question to ModSecurity that doesn't let me use file_get_contents and readfile   :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [Filesystem API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API)?.

The method of your choice would probably be `get_contents()` or `get_contents_array()`

Comment: guess you can use it, but it is like using a rocket to deliver pizza to the next block

Comment: @MarkKaplun : I could love rockets if they solve my issue   :-)

Comment: filesystem api requires human input. I can't think of any real world usage for reading a file in which you will want to stop execution to get user and password info from the user. Your problems are likely related to misconfigured server and it is much better to solve the real problems instead of trying to hack around them

Comment: @MarkKaplun: now I red your reply. Well, I would not say "misconfigured", but simply "over-configured". Anyway: when you have absolutely no control over the firewall in a shared hosting environment, the only thing you can do is "hacking around"